# In Python, how to make discord bot send 3 different message at the specific time, only once, without conflicting my main code?

Tags: python, timer, discord, discord.py, bots

The problem is I want to integrate 'send message' command to an existing code which then conflicts with the main code.

I have tried 'loop' messages, for example: wait 5 minutes and then send 'Your message.' in every 100 minutes but it gets in the loop and doesn't load my main code.

**Switching the order results:**

**'loop-message' code before the main code:**
After I receive the message I want on my discord channel, I press ctrl^C to abort, only after that my bot starts to load but after loading eventually stops again because of abortion. $bb commands never work because main code didn't load.

**'loop-message' code after the main code:**
My bot loads itself, works perfectly but never loads the 'loop-message'. When I ctrl^C, I receive 'coroutine was never awaited.' error. I never receive the message because 'loop-message' didn't load.

**What I need?**
I need to run both of these commands at the same time without conflict, bot answering my questions and at the 19.30 it sends automatic message and again, after that still, the bot can answer my questions.

I want the bot to send multiple delayed messages, for example msg1 sent on 19.30 msg2 sent on 19.33, only once at the specified time meanwhile not interrupting its ability to answer '$bb message' commands.

Here is my code without 'loop-message' code in it:

```
import discord,os

from neuralintents import GenericAssistant

chatbot = GenericAssistant('intents.json')
chatbot.train_model()
chatbot.save_model()

print("Bot is active. . .")

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("$bb"):
        response = chatbot.request(message.content[4:])
        await message.channel.send(response)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using threads, an example is below

```
import time
import threading
# Only the module 'threading' is needed (the module 'time' is for example purposes)

# function with the loop inside of it
def startloop():
  while True:
    print("loop")
    time.sleep(1)

# Start the function with no arguments
threading.Thread(target=startloop).start()

# Start a thread with arguments
# threading.Thread(target=startloop, args=('arg1', 'arg2')).start()

# make sure the main thread is still running
print("Main thread is still running!")
```